# Cast number type to BigDecimal TypeScript ( Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, casting, numbers, bigdecimal

I need to send a *BigDecimal* value from my angular front-end part to the java back-end. I tried to find a valuable solution but it seems that **TypeScript** knows only *number* type.

Is there any way to declare/cast a *BigDecimal* attribute in my angular project?

```
private totalPrice: number;
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't type variables : it only knows strings and numbers. If you want a BigDecimal in your back-end, consider parsing it in Java once you receive it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After couple of libraries tried, [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) seems the best:

Install the library using the following command in root folder:

> $ npm install --save big.js

Import:

> import Big from 'big.js';

Use:

```
private totalPrice: any;
this.totalPrice = Big(number_value).toPrecision(2) --> (e.g. 15.00)
```

Comment: You can add the TypeScript definition too, according its docs: https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/#typescript